# How to escape characters in a string and also show the escaped characters?

Tags: c, escaping

How can I place `\` before `"` of a string in C with out parsing the string character by character?

Actually,we are using `sprintf` to take the string and we are forming JSON response. But JSON is giving us error as it expects `\` to be there before `"`.

For example, if the string is in the format :

```
"hi "hello" bye"
```

I should get it in format of

```
"hi \"hello\" bye"
```

Comment: First, I'm sure this is a typo, but for me, a backslash is ``\``, you might want to edit your question to reflect that. Second, can't you escape the `"` in the `sprintf`. Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: code : json_resp->offset += sprintf(&json_resp->buffer[json_resp->offset], "\n\""JSON_FIELD_EVENT_SYNOPSIS"\": \"%s\",", utf8_str); Here utf8_str is the string which contains double quotes in between the string. so i want to take care of adding backslash before " to give proper JSON format with out checking character by character in a string

Comment: What's meant by "without parsing the string character by character"? Not doing this yourself (so you're asking for a library with a function doing this) or not at all? The latter is impossible, if you don't know where the characters are which need escaping. Also note, that JSON requires newlines replaced by `"\\n"` rather than `"\\\n"` etc. How are these strings generated? Maybe you could handle such characters upon creation.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the backslash in the sprintf by adding `\\` befor `\"`:

```
json_resp->offset += sprintf(&json_resp->buffer[json_resp->offset], 
               "\n\\\""JSON_FIELD_EVENT_SYNOPSIS"\\\": \\\"%s\\\",", utf8_str);
```

You should consider using `snprintf` to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: JSON_FIELD_EVENT_SYNOPSIS is a macro we are already using backslash to display it with in quotes and not facing the problem because of that. Problem is with utf8_str which contains double quotes in between .for example if utf8_str contains string [ The rich "earn" decades at] the above code gives :                      "synopsis":"The rich "earn" decades at" .And this is given as an input to browser and it is throwing error as there is no \ before double quotes in between

Answer (score 0):

Look at it piece by piece, rather than confused by the whole thing in one go.

You want to see a `\`, which needs escaping: `\\`.

Next, you want to see `"`, which also needs escaping : `\"`.

So all together it's:

```
printf("hi \\\"hello\\\" bye")
```

It looks nastier and more confusing than it actually is if you break it down as above - there's no special rule to it, it's just stringing (*ahem*..) characters together that you already know how to escape.

Comment: In the above code explicitly user is taking care placing \ before ". In a bulk string which is given as input to sprintf which contains double quotes and no idea where the quotes are present.In this scenario how to handle it as above first given solution did not help me :(.

Comment: simple explanation : Earlier in our code we used to check character by character of the input string, if we find special characters we used to place // before " and form final output string. Now we want to avoid it as character by character checking takes more time. so i am searching for alternate solution.